# Effects of a voltage divider on an audio DAC

Tags: audio, voltage-divider, dac

**Background**:

I'm planning on using a [TI TS5A22364 SPDT Switch with Negative Signaling](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a22364.pdf) to connect AGND to the Left and Right Channels of the [TI PCM5102A Audio DAC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5102a.pdf) when the DAC is powered down as an analog mute solution, since the XSMT functionality of the DAC does not meet my needs.

The TS5A22364 supports a maximum voltage swing of 5.5v. The PCM5102A outputs 2.1v RMS which is (2.1 * sqrt(2)) * 2 = 5.93Vpp + 7% FSR = 6.355Vpp / 2 = -3.1775v - 3.1775v which puts it above the 5.5v maximum of the TS5A22364 (even though the L/R channels won't be routed through the switch, the outputs share this maximum and voltage above it could trigger the ESD diodes).

**Proposed Solution**:

Using a voltage divider (R1=2710Ω, R2=10kΩ) on the L/R channels of the PCM5102A to drop the voltage to 5v.

**Questions**:

Are there any issues with this solution or better methods than the voltage divider?

My limited understanding of analog audio leads me to believe that the voltage divider should not impact quality, but only inhibit volume. **Is this correct?**

Comment: It depends. What is the audio feeding into after this analog switch?

Comment: @Hearth - The DAC feeds into an amplifier.

Comment: If the amplifier has a high input impedance and you don't have to drive any long wires to get to it, then you should be fine.

Comment: @Hearth - The wire run is only about 16", but I'm unsure of the specs of the amp (this is an in-car integration). The DAC works just fine with the voltage divider or the switch in place, FWIW.

Comment: wouldn't the divider divide more on positive current than negative (audio is AC)

Comment: @dandavis - I'm not sure -- can you point me towards a source on that? I tried googling, but couldn't find anything definitive.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Why would anything be different?

Comment: because r1 and r2 depend on polarity. unless they were the same, reversing the current flow would invert the ratio, right?

Comment: @dandavis as the same end of the voltage divider would be connected to Ground(0v reference) and the other end would vary above and below ground, the voltage divider will maintain its ratio over both polarities, so long as it shares the same ground as the signal.  For a voltage divider to function with reasonable accuracy, it must pass a constant current that dwarfs the current tapped off of it(>100:1 ratio, probably >1000:1 for this application.).  The other concern is thermal interference(changes to the signal caused by temperature changes/difference in the voltage divider.)

Comment: These problems are solved by high impedance on the tap(low current input on the device receiving the signal) and keeping the resistors of the voltage divider in close proximity and/or thermally linked(potted together).